# Notebook search with snippets programmatically

Tags: front-end, notebooks, searching

The normal "find" function in large notebooks hangs. I'd like to implement in-notebook find programmatically with displayed snippets of the results:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
NotebookFileName[EvaluationNotebook[]]
index = CreateSearchIndex[{NotebookFileName[]}]
(*I want to search for snippets of this notebook that contain the word "dog" using the index:*)    
TextSearch[NotebookFileName[], "dog"][All]    
(*This cell also contains the word dog, so there should be two results:*)    
TextSearch[index, SearchQueryString["dog"]][All, "Snippet"]
```

I would like the results to show up like they do in the reference for TextSearch, preferrably with the index auto-updated in the background at regular intevals and with deep hyperlinks from the yellow highlights into the current notebook:

[image]